# Algorithm to find the k sets of values from N sets such that the number of unique values across the k sets is maximised

Tags: optimization, combinations, combinatorics

I have a database of `N` billboards giving the IDs of all the people that saw each billboard. I need to find the `k` billboards that have been seen by the largest number of unique people across the `k` billboards.

As an example:

- I have `N = 3` billboards: billboard 1 was seen by persons `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'`, billboard 2 was
  seen by person `'b'` and billboard 3 was seen by persons `'c'` and `'d'`
- `k = 2`
- The solution is billboards 1 & 3, which together were seen by four people (`'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'` and `'d'`)

So each billboard represents a set of values, and I need to find the `k` billboards from the `N` available that have the highest number of unique values.

I can't do this with brute force because of the huge number of potential combinations (>10K billboards in my database), **is there an algorithm that more quickly find an optimal or near-optimal solution**? Speed here is more important than getting the answer exactly right.

Preferably I would also like to be able to constrain the algorithm such that the sum of the costs of the selected billboards was below a certain value, this isn't strictly required though.

I'm thinking this is similar to some of the combinatorial optimisation problems described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization), in particular the knapsack problem [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem), except that these problems are working with sets of numbers rather than sets of sets. My maths skills are sketchy so I haven't been able to work out whether I could modify these equations to suit my needs.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like [this problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_coverage_problem)

Comment: exactly what I was after, thank you!